# Kendo ui list view losing focus when changing data

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-datasource, kendo-template, kendo-listview

I have a kendo ui listview with a template the conditionally hides elements based on the underlying data. An example would be as follows:

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="template">
    <div class="product">
        <img src="../content/web/foods/#= ProductID #.jpg" alt="#: ProductName # image" />
        <h3>#:ProductName#</h3>
        <p>#:kendo.toString(UnitPrice, "c")#</p>
        <div>
          # if (Discontinued) { #
                Discontinued Product
          # } #
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

If i modify the underlying dataSource items to set Discontinued with the following code:

```
data[index].set('Discontinued', true);
```

If the index is the currently selected item then that item looses focus and is no longer selected.

Please see the following dojo example http://dojo.telerik.com/UlOze, select an item from the list and then set it to discontinued.

Has anybody found a solution / workaround for this issue ?

Thanks.

------------- FINAL SOLUTION --------------

Following on from dimodi's answer below I pieced together the solution.. For this to work the dataSource must have the schema -> model -> id property set.

1st capture the currently selected data item:

```
      var selectedItem = $(listElement).find(".k-state-selected");
      var selectedDataItem = list.dataItem(selectedItem);
```

2nd: After calling .set re-find the data item and set the k-state-selected class. This is nessesary as the list component is regenerating the uid's.

```
     if (selectedDataItem) {
        var newSelectedItem = list.dataSource.get(selectedDataItem.ProductID)
        var uid = newSelectedItem.uid;
        jQuery("[data-uid='" + uid + "']").addClass("k-state-selected");
      }
```

I've updated the original dojo to show this solution, incase it helps someone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a data item is changed, its corresponding ListView item is re-rendered to apply the changes. As a result, the selection is lost, as it is a purely visual feature that is not persisted across rebinds. You can check if an item is selected before using **set()** and then restore the selection manually by applying a **k-state-selected** class to the  element afterwards.

Comment: I can't seem to get this solution working, when the underlying data is changed the addClass does not work but if nothing is changed then it does work. I've tried using a setTimeout to see if that helps but no joy. Did you have to do anything else to make this work ?

Comment: Forgive the comment above. I've just noticed that the listview is regenerating the uid's of the data source elements. I've corrected the code to cope with this and it now works.